# Excel macro with $ symbol

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am very new at Excel. So i can't understand the meaning of the following line:

```
=D$4*L27*B8
```

here ,

```
L27 = .03
B8 = 5
D = 90 elbow
```

I am confused about D value, because it comes form a Column(first value) and L27 is beside this Column.

Comment: A `$` around a range reference simply makes that reference absolute. For more see <http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/referencing.php>. But from what you wrote, the formula doesn't make sense with the value `90 elbow`? `=D$4*L27*B8` basically says `90 elbow * .03 * 5`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that's not a macro, that's a formula.

The `$` sign indicates that the row should be fixed.  Should you drag and copy the cell down to the next row, it would read:

```
=D$4*L28*B9
```

While the D cell in the formula doesn't change, the L and B cells will.

Answer (score 0):

```
=D$4*L27*B8
```

$ means `absolute referencing`. So when you copy and paste this formula in next 5 cells it will become

```
=D$4*L27*B8
=D$4*L28*B9
=D$4*L29*B10
=D$4*L30*B11
=D$4*L31*B12
```

As you can see the `$` has made sure that row number `4` is fixed when the formula is copied. Usually this is used when you have a constant in an expression and you want to keep that same across various cells.

Comment: thank you, but can say one thing. here row number 4 is from which column? you mean the column where D value is available?

Comment: Yeah and in case you want to make it fixed the formula will read... `=$D$4*L27*B8`

Comment: but row number 4 is a text, so how it is possible to calculate? sorry, I am new at excel , just need to make a app.